# How to find remainder?

Tags: number-theory

$$a=r\mod (r+1) \ \ \forall r\in\{2,3,4,\dots,9\}$$

Then how do we find $'x'$ if $$a=x\mod 11$$

I get $$2a=9\mod11$$ but that does not help.

Please keep solution simple , i don't now number theory.

---

The above is the crux what I got from the question:

> Let $n_1,n_2,... $ be an increasing sequence of natural numbers each of which leaves remainder $r+1$ when divided with $r\in\{2,3,....9\}$. Find the remainder when $n_{2008}$ is divided with $11$.

Comment: The edit has made it a much different question (but my answer still gives you what you need to solve it).

Comment: The quoted problem is underdetermined. The answer is not unique given only that $\,n_i\,$ is an increasing natural  sequence. Probably you omitted some essential details in the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2a\equiv9\pmod {11}\equiv -2\implies a\equiv-1\pmod {11}\equiv10$$

---

Alternately, as $2\cdot 6=12\equiv1\pmod{11}\implies 2^{-1}\equiv6$

$2a\equiv 9\pmod{11}\implies a\equiv2^{-1}\cdot9\equiv 6\cdot9\equiv 10\pmod {11} $

If $a\equiv r\pmod{r+1}\equiv-1\implies (r+1)$ divides $a+1 \ \ \forall r\in\{2,3,4,\dots,9\} $

If $m_i$ divides $b,$ we know lcm$(m_i)$ will divide $b$

**EDIT**:  to answer the changed question

Here lcm$(3,4,\cdots,9,10)=5\cdot 8\cdot7\cdot 9=2520$

So, $n_i\equiv-1\pmod{2520}=2520c_i-1$ for some integer $c_i$s

For $n_i$ to be natural number $n_i=2520c_i-1>0\implies c>0\implies c_{\text{min}}=1$

So, if we choose, any arbitrary set of increasing positive integers for $c_i,$ we shall get an increasing sequence of natural numbers satisfying the given condition and solution will depend on the choice of $c_i$s

Now if we take $c_i=i$ for $i\ge1,$

$n_{2008}=2520\cdot 2008-1$

$\equiv1\cdot6-1\pmod {11}$ as $2520\equiv1\pmod {11}$ and $2008\equiv6\pmod {11}$

$\implies n_{2008}\equiv5\pmod{11}$

Comment: I had got the same , but answer is somehow $5$.Well this is final equation what I got in a problem to solve. I can provide full question if you think I may be wrong at this equation.

Comment: @user007, please share complete problem

Comment: Done. I think now you'll find my mistake.

Comment: +1 This is great. Can you also tell the flaw in my reduced form?

Comment: @user007, how have you reached at $2a\equiv9\pmod {11}$

Comment: adding $a\equiv 4(\mod 5) $ and $a\equiv 5 (\mod 6)$. Or any two consecutive ..

Comment: @user007, where have you find this formula? How has it been derived?

Comment: Formula for what? any $n$  of the sequence satisfy the above two $\equiv$ relations. Can't we add?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8928/discussion-between-user007-and-lab-bhattacharjee)

Comment: @user, NO, you certainly can't add $x\equiv a\pmod b$ and $x\equiv c\pmod d$ to get $x\equiv a+c\pmod{b+d}$. In this problem, it only gives you the right answer by coincidence, sort of like cancelling the nines gets you $29/95=2/5$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Well,I got a wrong answer.Answer is "5" annd I had got "10" as shown above by lab..

Comment: The problem is underdetermined. The only properties of the sequence given in the problem is that $\,n_i\,$ is an increasing sequence of naturals. This answer assumes additional properties of the sequence. It would be a good idea to explicitly state these additional hypotheses that you presume.

Comment: @user78535, I think $c_{min}=1$ was sufficient

Comment: @lab No it is not. It seems that you are also assuming that the sequence is geometric. Generally, if one assumes more than is stated in the OP, then one should explicitly state what those assumptions are.

Comment: @KeyIdeas, got your point. Could please have a look into the edited version?

Answer (score 1):

Find the least common multiple $L$ of the numbers $3,4,\dots,10$. Then $$a=L-1+kL$$ where $k$ is arbitrary. There is no restriction on $a$ modulo $11$ (unless there's more information on $a$, such as if you take the smallest possible $a$, which is $L-1$).

Comment: With the revised question, you now want $k=2007$.

Comment: +1 I got your point but will that mean, that I have to find $n_{2008}$ and then check it?

Comment: I have given you the formula for the numbers $n_1,n_2,\dots$; you get them by taking $k=0,1,\dots$. So you find $n_{2008}$ by, as I said, putting in $k=2007$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chinese reminder Theorem. It looks to me that you have the relations
$$\begin{align}
a&\equiv4\mod{5}\\
a&\equiv6\mod{7}\\
a&\equiv7\mod{8}\\
a&\equiv8\mod{9}\\
\end{align}$$
and all of the other relations give redundant information. There is a unique solution modulo $5\cdot 7\cdot8\cdot9=2520$. Since each of the moduli divide this number, $2519$ is a solution for $a$. So $a\equiv 2519\mod{2520}$. Now what would $a$ be modulo $11$? Anything is possible since $11$ does not divide $2520$. Are you sure this is the question that was asked? If $a$ is supposed to be the smallest positive solution, then $x\equiv2519\equiv0\mod{11}$. If $a$ is the smallest solution in absolute value, then $x\equiv-1\mod{11}$.

---

Now with the full question posted, do you see how $n_1=2519$? Continue to find $n_{2008}$.

Comment: I have added the full question. Sorry.

Comment: Life is much easier if you write the congruences as $a\equiv-1\pmod5$, and so on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Agreed!